# Run DrRacket plugin body only after all plugins initialized, error: phase2: can only be called in phase: 'init-complete

Tags: plugins, ide, racket

I'm trying to make a small drracket plugin that prints the definitions text reference object to the console on start up.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
#lang racket/unit
(require drracket/tool)
(import drracket:tool^)
(export drracket:tool-exports^)

(define (phase1) (void))
(define (phase2)
  (define def (drracket:get/extend:get-definitions-text))
  (writeln def))
```

However, when I install this plugin and start up DrRacket, I get the following error (full message at bottom of post):

```
phase2: can only be called in phase: 'init-complete
```

Which makes sense. Looking at the docs for `drracket:get/extend:extend-unit-frame`, which is used by `drracket:get/extend:get-definitions-text` say:

> Once this function is called, drracket:get/extend:extend-unit-frame raises an error, disallowing any more extensions.

So, I'm guessing that `phase2` is not late enough to assume that all other plugins are initialized. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any insertion points where I can run the code later than `phase2`. (If, for example, I just put it in the body of the unit, it will run before `phase1` or `phase2`.)

So, where is the appropriate place to to run `drracket:get/extend:get-definitions-text`?

Complete error message:

```
Error in phase 2 for tool #<path:/Users/leif/test/dplugpkg/tool.rkt>; #f

phase2: can only be called in phase: 'init-complete
  context...:
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/unit.rkt:528:6: get-definitions-text%
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/get-extend.rkt:119:0: get-base-definitions-text%
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/get-extend.rkt:69:2: get-built
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/arrow-higher-order.rkt:361:33
   /Users/leif/test/dplugpkg/tool.rkt:20:0: phase2
   .../more-scheme.rkt:261:28
   [repeats 23 more times]
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/tools.rkt:432:0: run-phases
   .../racket/unit.rkt:998:20
   "/Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/tool-lib.rkt": [running body]
   temp37_0
   for-loop
   run-module-instance!125
   "/Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/drracket-normal.rkt": [running body]
   temp37_0
   for-loop
   ...
instantiate: contract violation
  expected: class?
  given: #f
  context...:
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/unit.rkt:1402:4
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/module-language.rkt:1578:4
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/debug.rkt:1907:4
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   [repeats 2 more times]
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/module-language-tools.rkt:88:4
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/syncheck/gui.rkt:2035:6
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   /Users/leif/Library/Racket/planet/300/development/cache/jowalsh/code-coverage.plt/1/4/tool.rkt:25:6
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   [repeats 1 more time]
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/gui-debugger/debug-tool.rkt:1156:6
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   ...
leif@FATT ~/test/dplugpkg $ drracket
Error in phase 2 for tool #<path:/Users/leif/test/dplugpkg/tool.rkt>; #f

phase2: can only be called in phase: 'init-complete
  context...:
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/unit.rkt:528:6: get-definitions-text%
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/get-extend.rkt:119:0: get-base-definitions-text%
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/get-extend.rkt:69:2: get-built
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/arrow-higher-order.rkt:361:33
   /Users/leif/test/dplugpkg/tool.rkt:20:0: phase2
   .../more-scheme.rkt:261:28
   [repeats 23 more times]
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/tools.rkt:432:0: run-phases
   .../racket/unit.rkt:998:20
   "/Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/tool-lib.rkt": [running body]
   temp37_0
   for-loop
   run-module-instance!125
   "/Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/drracket-normal.rkt": [running body]
   temp37_0
   for-loop
   ...
instantiate: contract violation
  expected: class?
  given: #f
  context...:
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/unit.rkt:1402:4
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/module-language.rkt:1578:4
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/debug.rkt:1907:4
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   [repeats 2 more times]
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/module-language-tools.rkt:88:4
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/drracket/private/syncheck/gui.rkt:2035:6
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   /Users/leif/Library/Racket/planet/300/development/cache/jowalsh/code-coverage.plt/1/4/tool.rkt:25:6
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   [repeats 1 more time]
   /Users/leif/rsrc/drracket/drracket/gui-debugger/debug-tool.rkt:1156:6
   /Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:3554:0: continue-make-object
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `phase1` and `phase2` certainly happen too early to use `drracket:get/extend:get-definitions-text`. You *can* however insert your own hook that will run on the creation of a new definitions-text object. You do this with the appropriately named `drracket:get/extend:extend-definitions-text`, which takes a [`mixin`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mixins.html?q=mixin#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._mixin%29%29) (a function of type `Class -> Class`). By putting the call in the body of the class, you can ensure that not only all plugins will be instantiated, but that it will be called for every new definitions text DrRacket makes. Your code will look something like this:

```
(define (def-mixin super%)
  (class super%
    (super-new)
    (define the-def-text
      (drracket:get/extend:get-definitions-text))
    (writeln the-def-text)))
```

Of course, by this point that is a reference to this mixins own class, and so using `this%` instead produces an identical plugin:

```
(define (def-mixin super%)
  (class super%
    (super-new)
    (define the-def-text this%)
    (writeln the-def-text)))

(drracket:get/extend:extend-definitions-text def-mixin)
```

Putting everything together, you end up with:

```
#lang racket/unit
(require drracket/tool)
(import drracket:tool^)
(export drracket:tool-exports^)

(define (def-mixin super%)
  (class super%
    (super-new)
    (writeln this%)))

(define (phase1) (void))
(define (phase2) (void))
(drracket:get/extend:extend-definitions-text def-mixin)
```